# how to perform sorting,search,pagination in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, sorting, search, pagination

I'm a fresher in codeigniter. I want to search,sort and apply pagination to my table.
I tried my best.when search code is working sorting may not work. i can't perform these three actions in a single table. please help me.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-do-pagination-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Bootstrap datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html). It has in built search, Sort and pagination too.

---

### **Sample of My code**

**In View**

```
<div style="clear: both; margin-top: 35px"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding: 0px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 " style="padding-right:0px;">
                <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="20%"></th>
                        <th width="15%"></th>
                        <th width="20%"></th>
                        <th width="15%"></th>
                        <th width="10%"></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?
                        foreach ( $ as $ )
                        {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $['']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $['']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $['']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $['']?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?
                        }

                    ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**In Controller**

```
$data[''] = $this->model_name->function_name();
```

**In Header**

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

---

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @ Abdulla yeah.. it is really helpful. :)

Comment: @SaranyaR happy to help :) Enjoy Coding

Comment: @SaranyaR this add this too `bootstrap-glyphicons.css`. Can download on bootstrap site